# How do I get the new updated data from react hooks or useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I get the newly updated data from react hooks or useEffect?

I loaded the parent components with the title: `Shoes` then change the input to `"New Shoes"` but the data inside my child components doesn't change, its still `"Shoes"`. how do I get it updated?

in the parent components:

```
<UrlInput
   value={url}
   title={title}
   baseURL={baseURL}
   onChange={this.onURLChange}
/>
```

Child component

```
const UrlInput = ({title}) => {
    const [newTitle, setTitle] = useState(title);

     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(title)
         setTitle(newTitle)
     })

  return (

  );
};
```

Comment: Why Is the title variable with a capital T in your useState constructor?

Answer (score 3):

You should add title as a dependency to useEffect and update state with `title` and not `newTitle`. Also the original state needs to be set with `title` and not `Title`.

```
const UrlInput = ({title}) => {
    const [newTitle, setTitle] = useState(title);

     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(title)
         setTitle(title)
     }, [title]);

  return (

  );
};
```

P.S. Also its an antipattern to copy props into state when state is directly derivable from props unless you need to modify the state locally.

Comment: Could you please share how you are updaring title in parent and does it trigger a re-render in child

Answer (score 1):

```
const UrlInput = ({title, ...rest}) => {
    const [newTitle, setTitle] = useState(title);

     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(title)
         setTitle(title)
     },[title]) 

  return (

  );
};
```

try replacing the code with the above one .You should pass a new value into setTitle() you were passing the same variable that stored the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

For the get, any state-specific change in a component use the useEffect(() => {},[specific condition here]).

You can follow this code here.

in the parent components:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');  // initial state parent 
const onURLChange = e => setTitle(e.target.value) ; set state parent from children triger 

<UrlInput
    value={url}
    title={title}
    baseURL={baseURL}
    onChange={this.onURLChange}
/>
```

Child component

```
const UrlInput =props => {
    const [newTitle, setTitle] = useState(props.Title);

     useEffect(() => {
         console.log(title)
         setTitle(newTitle)
     },[props.Title])

  return (

  );
};
```